# Django vs GAE + Django vs GAE + other framework

Tags: django, google-app-engine, frameworks, app-engine-patch

I`m looking for opinion which one is better for building web applications(web sites).
I have some experience with Django, and some with Google App Engine and App-Engine-Patch
for Django. And it seems to me that only Django is working faster than the GAE implementation.
Is there some other frameworks that simplify the developments process, providing forms creating,
user management, url resolving etc.

Thanks in advance,
Ilian Iliev

P.S. I  am also interested in GAE and webapp framework case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have experience with Django, I would stick with Django. You'll improve quicker than you would by jumping to something entirely new.

If you are finding GAE difficult to work with, try a Django-friendly host: [Webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com) are well-liked in the Django community, and (from what I can tell) they seem to make setting up the site pretty simple. Then you can leave behind GAE's eccentricities and concentrate on improving your Django skills.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, the reason that I`m not 100% sure for GAE is that I have a bad experience with its speed in combination with app-engine-patch, but it was my first project with both of them(and also 1st python project) so I`m not sure is this cause by the patch or by my self.

Answer (score 3):

app-engine-patch and google-app-engine-django are dead.

Just use [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel). It allows you to use Django-1.2 (development version) with some query-related limitations with App Engine (or with NoSQL databases such as couchdb).

Comment: I see the news for the app-engine-patch retirement and the django nonrel but didn`t have the time to check it out. Is there a lot of differences?